# Transparency Libgdx Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

We are programming a game in Android with libgdx. It's a Doodle Jump like.

At a point of the game, we want plateforms to disapear step by step by reducing the transparency of the picture. We've tested many things but nothing works.

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(picture, posX, posY, width, heigth);
bach.end();
```

We also tried with this, but it doesn't work :

```
batch.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: last argument of setColor is alpha, you tried below 1.0f right? Because alpha=1 is full transparency

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SpriteBatch#setColor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#setColor%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) works: you didnt change the alpha (last value), thats why it didnt work for you.

```
batch.begin();
batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5F); //0.5F is the alpha value that you want (0-1)
batch.draw(picture, posX, posY, width, heigth);
batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1); //change it back to full opacity white, for the other objects to render correctly
bach.end();
```

If you start using [Sprite](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html)s, [mrzli answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21026610/1895303) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, it's working :D !!! 
I think that my error was that I didn't put this ligne 'batch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);'

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Sprite, and then set alpha using this method:

```
public static void setSpriteAlpha(Sprite sprite, float alpha) {
    Color c = sprite.getColor();
    sprite.setColor(c.r, c.g, c.b, alpha);
}
```

This works for sure, since I used it in my Doodle Jump clone.

Here is some example usage:

```
batch.begin();
sprite.setBounds(posX, posY, width, height);
setSpriteAlpha(sprite, 0.5f);
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

If it helps you, you can find the source code for the entire game [here](https://github.com/mrzli/hellhopper), and use it pretty much any way you want to (MIT licence). It is simple and probably not much fun, but it is completed.

You can also check out the result on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turbogerm.helljump).

Comment: No need to made a method for getting the Sprite color to modify its alpha, you can simply use [Sprite#setAlpha](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setAlpha%28float%29)

Comment: @Lestat You're right, I can't even remember why I started doing it this way. I guess I didn't see that method...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I'll try your solution ;)

PS : I've download your game in Play Store, your game is great ! You've done a good job ^^

Comment: I have not found that setAplha method in the class Spirit, then I could not try your solution :/ Any way, with Lestat's solution it's working. Thanks for your help and your fast responses !

Comment: @user3178291 First of all, thank you :). You are correct, `Sprite.setAlpha()` exists in documentation (as Lestat pointed out), but now that I checked I can see no such method in libgdx 0.9.9 code. Regardless, my answer will work since I DON'T use this apparently non-existent `Sprite.setAlpha()`, but a custom `setSpriteAlpha()` (first snippet in answer).

Comment: The method was added after the 0.9.9 stable release, thus only available in the nightlies build. (Which I highly recommend you to use! :) ) this is the [pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/c4b3a54b614389b58e74fa1143d334ae0430767c)

Comment: @Lestat It just seems like additional work, downloading and replacing jars, and they can potentially have more bugs, so I have a habit of using only stable releases. Unless of course there is some significant benefit to using nightlies, and having some non-critical functionality a few month earlier is currently not enough for me :)

Comment: Yer a wizard mrzli, I mean yer right :p it is additional work. But it wouldn't be if you used the nightlies from the beginning. I have used them since I started even before 0.9.9 release. And never had a single problem related to a bug. It can have some potential bugs of course but I haven't encountered them. And most of the time when in the forums someone reports a bug, usually the answer is like this "Use the nightlies, its already been fixed there". So I can tell you for sure, the stable has more bugs then the nightlies, the team does not do bug fix backporting.

Comment: @Lestat In that case, I might just do that, Hagrid ;D